# Do universality classes depend only on the hamiltonian or also the lattice?

Tags: condensed-matter, phase-transition

The example I want to investigate is 2d Transverse Field Ising Model. On a square ferromagnetic lattice it belongs to the 3d classical Ising class. But what if we put it on a triangular lattice with antiferromagnetic couplings (frustrated)? What if we put on a square lattice with odd number of ferromagnetic couplings (again frustrated)? I would like to know the universality classes these belong to, references are also appreciated.

Comment: It is known that the triangular lattice AFM Ising model has an ordering transition belonging to 3d XY class. A good reference is https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0011250, where they also discussed several other frustrated Ising models.